# How to store a date command to a Variable in CMD

Tags: cmd

Let's say I want to store the date in a variable and use the if statment to call the variable. This is what i did so far 
@echo off

```
FOR /F %F IN ('date.cmd') do date SET result=%F

IF  %result%== 11/14/2013(echo complete) ELSE
(echo failed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the inbuilt `%date%` variable?

Note that `%date% may contain the dayname and also the separator and sequence of elements may also vary between users.

Perhaps

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%date%") do if "%%b"=="" (set result=%%a) else (set result=%%b)
echo result is %result%
IF %result%==11/14/2013 (echo complete) ELSE (echo failed)
```

would suit.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

Parsing the `date` output gives you different results as it depends on the locale and also the user can change the date format.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "result=%MM%/%DD%/%YYYY%"

IF "%result%"=="11/14/2013" (echo complete) ELSE (echo failed)
pause
```